# fullCalendar Not Populating Fetch Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have a single event array of objects that I want to post to the fullCalendar. If I create an array of objects that isn't dynamic from a fetch response, it works fine. I get the items from a fetch, create a new object with the response, then push each individual object to an array. Before my .catch(), I `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', approvedReq);` then in my .fullCalendar initialization, I define the array I created as the event source. Please see my code below:

```js
const requestsApproved = new Request(
    "/items?$expand=EmployeeName&$select=ID,Title,EmployeeName/Title,EmployeeName/Id,StartDate,EndDate,TotalHours,Status&$filter=Status eq 'Approved'"
    , {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',        
        headers: new Headers({
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        })
    }
);

const approvedReq = [];

fetch(requestsApproved)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        const items = data.d.results;
        items.forEach((item) => {
            const approveReqItems =
            {
                id: item.ID,
                title: item.Title,
                start: item.StartDate,
                description: 'Request',
                end: item.EndDate,
                color: '#104723',
                textColor: '#b3ab7d',
            };
            approvedReq.push(approveReqItems);
            //console.log(item.Title,item.EventDate,item.EndDate);
        });
        console.log(approvedReq);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', approvedReq);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
    
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: '',
        right: 'title month,agendaWeek'
    },
    events: approvedReq,
    displayEventTime: false,
});
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css' />
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: The question is a bit hard to undestand.  What is the problem?  Your code above adds the events 2x, which you shouldn't do ... My guess is you are running into async problems?  `approvedReq` won't be availble until your `fetch()` is done, but your `.fullCalendar()` initialisation code is trying to use that variable on page load.  Can you just use the `fetch` as your `events` source?  The docs include an example of how to do this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function

Comment: Agreed, the problem is that you're assigning approvedReq to the calendar before it's been populated (because fetch requests are asynchronous). But you can follow the link Don't Panic provided - this gives you a way to run the fetch request via fullCalendar and then a callback is provided through that function which gives you the ability to asynchronously pass the event list back to fullCalendar once it's received. There's also the advantage that it's dynamic - you can return just the events which apply to the current date range, and then fetch more only if/when they're actually needed.